# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY with JsonAvroConverter

Tags: java, json, avro

I have a JSON that look like this:

```
[
    {"id":1},
    {"id":2},
    {"id":3}
]
```

Of course there is more atributes but this is enough to reproduce the error.

I am trying to convert that JSON to a `Generic.Record` by using the method `convertToGenericDataRecord` from `JsonAvroConverter` class.

My sample code:

```
    String json = "[{\"id\":1},{\"id\":2},{\"id\":3}]";
    String schema =
    "{" +
    "   \"type\" : \"array\"," +
    "   \"items\" : {\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ids\", \"fields\":[{ \"name\" : \"id\", \"type\" : \"string\" }]}" +
    "}";

    JsonAvroConverter converter = new JsonAvroConverter();

    GenericData.Record record = converter.convertToGenericDataRecord(json.getBytes(), new Schema.Parser().parse(schema));
```

It is throwing: `Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token`

Answer (score 1):

[] brackets in json are usually used to denote a list.

to denote a hash map you will want just

```
{
   "key": "value",
   "key": "value"
}
```

Comment: I want to collect the entire list and afterwards write in a avro file where each element would be a row.